# xcode 5.1 crashes when old xib file is opened

Tags: xcode, crash, interface-builder, xib

I have an application that was built using Xcode 4.x a while ago.  Today, I tried to update the app, but Xcode gives me the following error.

"Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255"

The problem seems to be related to MainWindow.xib because when I try to open it in Xcode, it crashes .  here is the crash log:

```
Process:         Xcode [4801]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1 (5084)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5084000000000000~21
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 444172641
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [314]
Responsible:     Xcode [4801]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-03-30 12:52:21.937 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  5F3D19A9-E9CE-6E7F-D1E6-13874A73646F

Sleep/Wake UUID: 94AB887F-E3ED-4944-92D6-E9C8274657DC

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B130a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-5038/InterfaceBuilder/WidgetIntegration/SimulatedMetrics/IBUISimulatedSizeMetrics.m:33
Details:  (initialTargetRuntime) should not be nil.
Object:   <IBUIFixedSimulatedSizeMetrics: 0x7f890bcc9090>
Method:   -initWithTargetRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f891bc15b90>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000103275825 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001020947a9 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000102094a8f _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010e0637c0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x000000010e064047 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x000000010e06434a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000010e0acc4e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000010e0ac682 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000010e0ad33c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000010e04f3c8 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
```

I have tried everything that is related to this question on stack overflow, but none of the remedies has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Apple about this and used one of my two free incident reports and asked for help.  The response was to file a bug report!

I ended up re-creating the xib.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same problem for me.

Latest Xcode
Xcode crashes when that particular Xib is viewed (MainWindow.xib).

I've researched around. Some mentioned custom fonts relating to multiple computer. Doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Decided to get back to my older computer and noticed that it was actually using Xcode 5.0 Developer Preview 6. I then downloaded Xcode 5.0 from Apple's developer achieve and it compiles and works perfectly fine. Went back to the Xcode 5.1 on the same computer and hoping that the 5.0 would somewhat update the XIB file and tried the same thing but it crashes again.